# Let $E$ and $F$ be a compact set on un metric space $(X,d)$. Show that dist$(E,F)>0$ if and only if $E \cap F = \emptyset $

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $E$ and $F$ be a compact set on un metric space $(X,d)$. Show that dist$(E,F)>0$ if and only if $E \cap F = \emptyset $

---

($\Leftarrow$)

if $E \cap F = \emptyset \ \ \ \ \ \text{then} \ \ \ \ \forall x,y ,\ \ \ \ \  x  \in E, \ \ \ \ y \in F  $  then $$inf \{ d(x,y)|x \in E , y \in F \}>0 \implies \text{dist}(E,F)>0$$

($\Rightarrow$)
my idea is to suppose that  $E \cap F \ne \emptyset.$ Let $z \in E\cap F$.
Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ and  $\{y_n\}$ both converge to z because the set E and F are compact.  Then arrive at a contradiction that dist$(E,F)=0$

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the second part is trivial, you don't need the compactness. The real place you need the compactness is in the first part. Prove d is continuous, since E and F are compact, d can attain its minimum on $E\times F$, then the inf is positive.

Comment: Im not sure why I need the compactness for $\Leftarrow$ direction. Im trying to find an exemple

Comment: @seito that's not hard to find an example, consider E=(0,1) and F=(1,2) in R.

Comment: ($\Leftarrow$) 
Since $E$ and $F$ is compact, there's a subsequence of  $x_{n_k} $ that converge to $x_0 \in E$ and $y_{n_k}$ converge to $y_0 \in F$. Then d(x,y) >0 ?

Comment: @seito I don't quite follow you, where are ${x_n}$ and ${y_n}$ from?

Comment: E is compact then E is sequentially compact. It follow that thers an arbitrary {xn} in E such that the subsequence  converge to x . Same thing with {yn} in F.

Comment: @seito you mean pick $x\belong E& and $y\belong F$, prove that d(x,y)>0?

Comment: yeah that right

Comment: @seito you don't really need to prove that, $x\ne y$ clearly implies d(x,y)>0, the real thing you need to prove is inf$\{d(x,y),x\in E, y\in F\}$>0

Comment: Ok ,how about I show that d$(xn ,yn,)>0 $ implies that inf{ $ d(x,y ) , x \in E, y \in F$ } $ > 0 $

Comment: @seito I still don't know where these sequences come from, maybe you should write the whole thing down.

Comment: can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Since E is compact it is sequentially compact. Chose an abritrary $\{ xn \} \subseteq E $ which the subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\} \rightarrow x_0$ in E and $\{ yn \} \subseteq F $ with  $\{y_{n_l}\} \rightarrow y_0$ in F. Then $d(x_n,y_n)>0 $. Since $x_0 \in E$ and $y_0 \in Y $ then d$(x_0,y_0)>0$.

Since $E \cap F = \emptyset$ , It is also true that $d(x_n, y_n) >0$. Then we get that:

$$inf \{ d(x,y,) | x \in E , y \in F \} > 0 $$

Comment: It seems not valid. How did you conclude the inf>0 from d(xn,yn)>0?

Comment: hmmm.. I think my anwser is not good because what if theres a point not in my sequence

Comment: anwser for your question : since {xn} is in E  and {yn} inF are arbitratry then d(xn,yn)>0

Comment: yeah, I know that d(xn,yn)>0, but why is the inf>0?

Comment: well if inf = 0 then theres a point which xn and yn converge to the same limit

Answer (score 0):

If inf=0, then there are sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ such that d(xn,yn) converges to 0. Pick subsequences xnk and ynk converges to x0 and y0 in E and F respectively. Then d(x0,y0)=0, which is a contradiction. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yeah I was about to edit my post to write that

Comment: @seito well, then, I think that works, but note that it also uses the property that d is continuous.

Comment: can you explain the property that d is continuous

Comment: In the above argument, we want to arrive a contradiction, namely, $d(x_0,y_0)=0$. That's done by ${\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} d(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})}=0$ and ${\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} d(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})}=d(x_0,y_0)$, the latter use the property that $d$ is continuous.

Comment: The proof of continuity of $d$ is not hard, actually, $d$ is Lipschitz continuous since $\lvert d(x_1,y)-d(x_2,y)\rvert \le d(x_1,x_2)$ and $\lvert d(x,y_1)-d(x,y_2)\rvert \le d(y_1,y_2)$.